# Route not found

Tags: symfony5

I have imported the following project [Gentella-admin-Symfony-5.](https://github.com/mamless/Gentella-admin-Symfony-5)

Now I wanted to create some new Controller and to create a default frontend route.

I have tried to create the route with annotations. But all failed. My Democontroller is created in this way

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     *
     * @Route("/number")
     */
    public function number(): Response
    {
        $number = random_int(0, 100);
        
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
            'number' => $number,
        ]);
    }
    
    /**
     *
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $number = "0815";
        
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
            'number' => $number,
        ]);
    }
}
```

But the call with:
https://localhost:8000/number
just ends up with: No route found for "GET /number"

the default page: https://localhost:8000/ ends up with the Symfony empty page and the profiler also shows: No route found for "GET /"

I am almost new to symfony (experienced in PHP anyway, but need to learn symfony right now).

For cross checkings I made a fresh project with composer with anntation usage from symfony route docs (lucky number Page). There all worked fine.

This is what makes me crazy, and why I am not able to create a default FE route.

Can someone help me out ?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I figured out so far, that the problem is caused by the default locale in the routes.yaml.

```
controllers:
    resource: '../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation
    prefix: /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app_locales%'
    defaults:
        _locale: '%locale%'
```

When I remove all starting from prefix, then I can access my home right now.

Now I need assistance "only", on how to find to correct, that my home can be accessed in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to Debug the Routes.

```
php bin/console debug:router
```

Here is the Link to Documentation: [Router Debuggen](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#debugging-routes)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After I analysed the project, I have seen, that there is an EventSubscriber to redirect on admin path calls in  RedirectToLocaleSubscriber.php with locale as prefix.

So my workaround was to extend this with my new created folder for frontend.

Anyway. I was wondering why the route to root (/) is not parsed correctly.

And I have seen the debug routes, and for me all looked fine.

I am not sure, if this is related to the content of the routes.yaml, where a prefix is defined as: prefix: /{_locale}

And how to modify to and handle excludes on it.